# Shiro-Guice Filter Chain Roles Configuration

Tags: java, security, roles, shiro

How can I configure the Roles in the `addFilterChain` Method??

in the INI file it is something like

```
[url]
/secure/** = authc, roles[admin]
```

How would it be in the Java method?

```
addFilterChain("/secure/**", ROLES);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ShiroWebModule provides a "config" method that mimics the INI [] syntax.

So the equivalent of your INI config would be:

```
addFilterChain("/secure/**", AUTHC, config(ROLES, "admin"));
```